# Plot year's quarter indicator in Chart

Tags: c#, plot, charts

I had came out with a Windows form application which is used to plot a line chart. My X-Axis values are of DateTime type whereas the Y-Axis are of Decimal type. In addition to my current chart, I wanted to include some vertical lines in my chart to represent a period (quarters of the year).

> Function to plot the chart:

```
private void PlotChart(string[] sortedRow)
{
    count = sortedRow(8);
    dateHolder.Add(count);
    spcPoint = Math.Round(sortedRow(7) * multiplier, decimalPoint);
    try
    {
        this.Chart1.Series("Result").Points.AddXY(count, spcPoint);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ErrorToString);
    }
}
```

I am passing a row by row of a CSV file to the above function and plotting the chart based on the values available in each row. I have accumulated all the DateTime values available in a List of DateTime called dateHolder. Note that the dateHolder's values are arranged in terms of increasing date from oldest to latest. Assume that I have data from the timespan of December 4th 2015 to November 30th 2017 My goal is as below: 
[image]

From the above image, there a some green lines. The green lines represents my quarterly period where:

```
1st line : 31st Dec 2015 (Q4 end 2015)
2nd line : 1st Jan 2016 (Q1 begin 2016)
3rd line : 31st Mar 2016 (Q1 end 2016)
4th line : 1st Apr 2016 (Q2 begin 2016)
5th line : 30th Jun 2016 (Q2 end 2016)

and so on...
```

> Function to plot the Quarterly indicator:

```
 private void PlotPeriodicIndicator()
    {
        int lastPoint = dateHolder.Count();
        DateTime startDate = dateHolder(0);
        DateTime endDate = dateHolder(lastPoint - 1);
        //No idea how to continue here
    }
```

Comment: There are various ways to do this: !) you could add a dedicated series to hold the lines. a bit nasty to avoid visible connections. 2) you can add VerticalLineAnnotations 3) you can draw the lines in a Paint event using the axis conversion functions to get the pixel coodinates. Imo 3 is the easiest and 2 the most 'chart-like' way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way that draws lines in the `PostPaint` event; it assumes you have a filled `List<DateTime> markers`:

```
private void chart1_PostPaint(object sender, ChartPaintEventArgs e)
{
    Axis ax = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
    Axis ay = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;

    foreach (DateTime d in markers)
    {
        int x = (int)ax.ValueToPixelPosition(d.ToOADate());

        int y0 = (int)ay.ValueToPixelPosition(ay.Minimum);
        int y1 = (int)ay.ValueToPixelPosition(ay.Maximum);

        e.ChartGraphics.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, x, y0, x, y1);
    }
}
```

Note that this should be in one of the Paint events as the axis functions are not always valid and the drawing is not permanent otherwise.

Here is the same effect using `Annotations`:

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].RecalculateAxesScale();
foreach (DateTime d in markers)
{
    VerticalLineAnnotation va = new VerticalLineAnnotation();
    va.AxisX = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
    va.AxisY = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;
    va.X = d.ToOADate();
    va.ClipToChartArea = chart1.ChartAreas[0].Name;
    va.IsInfinitive = true;
    va.LineColor = Color.Red;
    va.Width = 1;
    chart1.Annotations.Add(va);
}
```

Note that we need to first enforce an axis calculation, when using the freshly set points; also that we need to assign the annotation axes to enforce using value coordinates instead of the default percentages.